# How to use fgets function in order to save specific words from a textfile and recommended datatype for saving?

Tags: c

Im trying to save certain words from a textfile in order to build a directed graph. The words in the textfile are names which corresponds to nodes. Later on I want to apply a traversal algorithm that can find the path between these nodes.

I am currently trying to construct the graph. I have managed to read in the file with fopen and the fgets function.

My question is, when reading a textfile with the fgets function, how can one store certain words from the file?(the nodes)
And do you recommend a certain datatype to store the words in if the goal is to be able to apply a traversal algorithm on them later on?

Pardon if my question is to simple, I am a beginner in programming.

In order for you to better understand what i am trying to do, my code looks like this:

```
void read_file(){
  char words[200];
  FILE *fP;
  fP = fopen("textfile.txt", "r");

   while(fgets(words, 200, fP)) {

      //Test to see if the file was read..
      printf("%s", words);



      //Here i want to save the Nodes:


    }
    fclose(fP);
  }
```

Edit:
An example of the format for the textfile is:

```
#Some nodes
14
SYD DAL # Sydney-Dallas
PAR BAR # Paris-Barcelona
CHI FRA # Chicago-Frankfurt
…and so on…
```

The three letters corresponds to nodes and the right hand side of the "#" sign corresponds to edges

The file starts with an "#" but that was the command for making a header it seems. It is like it is now but without the blank lines. The number is supposed to correspond to the actual number of nodes. But I haven't typed all the nodes.

Comment: Heard of `scanf` or `sscanf`?

Comment: You could split the line into words using `strtok` and then use `strdup` to create individual storage for each word.

Comment: The question is too broad and also somewhat unclear, you should show at least a small sample of `textfile.txt`. You can [edit] your question. Then we can at least point you in the right direction.

Comment: To remove the trailing newline after `fgets()` you can use `words[strcspn(words, "\n")] = 0;`.

Comment: @enhzflep yes but im not sure how to use sscanf in this case, any tip?

Comment: @stark, when searching on the web, i did find that strtok could be used but that it was not recommended. Is it a good function to use in this case?

Comment: @Jabberwocky sorry for that, i have edited the question. You should see an example in the bottom of the question. The three letters corresponds to nodes and the right hand side of the "#" sign corresponds to edges.

Comment: @Luca_Toni please [edit] your question and format the sample correctly, it's unclear if _"Some nodes 14"_ is part of the file or not.

Comment: @Luca_Toni I edited for you, are the blank lines actually in the file? Does is the first line of the file really `"Some nodes"` ?? What's the `14`?

Comment: stark's comment still stands. The rest of your question is really too broad.

Comment: @Jabberwocky, sorry havent used the forum for other than searching on existing topics before. 
The file starts with an "#" but that was the command for making a header it seems.
It is like it is now but without the blank lines. The number is supposed to correspond to the actual number of nodes. But i havent typed all nodes.

Comment: @Luca_Toni don't describe your sample but format it correctly

Comment: @Jabberwocky, edited. Thanks

Comment: @Luca_Toni - sure. Same one I give everyone - READ THE DOCS. Then test your knowledge with some very simple and trivial programs designed to do nothing other than test your understanding of how a function is used. As for the ones I mentioned - they both use the same format specifiers as printf. I actually forgot (arguably) the most useful one for you - `fscanf`. Here's an sscanf ex: `sscanf("14\r\n", "%d", &someIntVar);` successful execution will result in the variable called someIntVar having the value 14 assigned to it. (The \r\n are the newline, carriage-return chars in your input)

Comment: @enhzflep: Be wary — using the trailing `\r\n` in the format string with `sscanf()` isn't too painful.  If you were using it with interactive I/O, it would be very bad.  Generally, avoid trailing white space in format strings for the `scanf()` family of functions.

Comment: You say that the number on its own is the number of nodes — does that mean the number of distinct three-letter combinations?  Or does it mean the number of lines?  Have you learned about `malloc()`, `realloc()` and `free()` yet — dynamic memory allocation?  The count line should be irrelevant — you can have the computer dynamically allocate more memory as needed (but don't increment the size by one each time more space is needed; double the amount of space allocated).   In the data shown, each line corresponds to an edge in the graph; the codes before the hash `#` are the nodes' abbreviations.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, Yes the number represents the unique nodes. I have learnt about these functions briefly, unsure how to use sscanf with malloc. It is also true that the each line corresponds to an edge. So i probably want to save both node and edge in order to make an traversal later on.